# Detail Steps to solve my Encryption time error using "crypto-browserify"

Tags: angular, typescript, types

I got this type of error on loading of my Angular 8 app

> default-encoding.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: process.version.split is not a function

How can i resolve this?
I'm using Angular 8, Nodejs 12.0 onwards.
I'm also using fully type Script Code.

```
import { Buffer } from 'buffer/';
import * as crypto from "crypto-browserify";
....
encrypt(plaintext): string {
if (!this.enabled)
return plaintext;
let buffer = new Buffer(plaintext);
let encrypted = crypto.privateEncrypt(this.privateKey, buffer);
alert(encrypted.toString('base64'))
}
decrypt(cypher): string {
if (!this.enabled)
return cypher;
let buffer = Buffer.from(cypher`enter code here`, 'base64');
let plaintext = crypto.publicDecrypt(this.publicKey, buffer);
alert(plaintext.toString('utf8'))
}
```

The error is

> **default-encoding.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: process.version.split is not a function**
>   at Object../node_modules/pbkdf2/lib/default-encoding.js (default-encoding.js:6)